# Convert boolean to integer in Scheme/Racket without conditionals?

Tags: scheme, racket

Is it possible to convert a boolean to either 0 or 1 in Racket without using `cond` or `if`? How would I do so?

For example, `(f true) -> 1` and `(f false) -> 0`.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using `intermediate student with lambda`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Here's an Intermediate Student solution (Leushenko's solution works in Intermediate Student too, serendipitously; they posted their solution before the OP's question change, too):

```
(define (boolean->integer b)
  (sub1 (length (memv b '(#t #f)))))
```

Note that in Intermediate Student, only `memv` has the standard Scheme behaviour. `memq` and `member` return booleans, for odd reasons.

Previous answers below are for standard Scheme (with SRFI 1, in the case of the `count` solution).

---

Óscar López's answer is correct, of course, but `or` and `and` are actually macros that eventually expand to `if`. So if those are unacceptable, we can exploit the read syntax instead:

```
(define (boolean->integer b)
  (define (char-offset x)
    (- (char->integer x) (char->integer #\f)))
  (define out (open-output-string))
  (write b out)
  (/ (char-offset (string-ref (get-output-string out) 1))
     (char-offset #\t)))
```

---

Other shorter, but cheating (in terms of actually doing branching behind the scenes) answers:

```
(define (boolean->integer b)
  (count values (list b))
```

Or, inspired by Leushenko's answer:

```
(define (boolean->integer b)
  (case b
    ((#f) 0)
    ((#t) 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you view library functions as black boxes (the `if` doesn't count if it was implemented in C?):

```
(define (b2i b)
  (cadr (assq b '((#t 1) (#f 0)))) )

(b2i #t)  ;-> 1
(b2i #f)  ;-> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(define (test x)
  (or (and x 1) 0))
```

For example:

```
(test true)
=> 1
(test false)
=> 0
```

Comment: This solution is really nice, but unfortunately it doesn't work in intermediate student. Is there a way to make this work in intermediate student?

Comment: @Linksku No, sorry but this won't work in "intermediate student" because of a restriction of that language that prohibits using `and`, `or` with non-boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of this one:

```
(define (f b)
  (length (remove b '(#f))))
```